# What is the opposite of "upfront payment"?

Tags: single-word-requests

What is the opposite of "upfront payment"? Something that would signify a payment done after the service has been used.

Comment: Even without including the word ***define***, the first result return by googling [*"**upfront payment**"*](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22upfront+payment%22&rlz=1C1CHBF_en-GBGB712GB712&oq=%22upfront+payment%22&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i61&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) says *"Upfront payment" is prepayment -- money you pay before you get the goods or service. In accounting, upfront payments are "unearned fees" and must be entered as liabilities on the balance sheet.* Voting to close for lack of prior research.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there are multiple alternatives to *upfront payment*, and no effort to find a solution has been demonstrated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is a trust relationship between the customer and service provider, payment can be charged [*on account*](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/o/on-account.asp), meaning on credit, to be settled at a later date, such as at the end of the month.

If payment doesn't need to be made all at once, especially on large-ticket items like vehicles or properties, then payment can be made in [*installments*](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/instalment-payment) over several weeks or months.

Accountants use the term of payment [*in arrears*](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/a/arrears.asp) (as opposed to payment *"in advance"*), although this also has an alternate interpretation, meaning that the customer hasn't paid the account on time (i.e. the account is *in* arrears).

Comment: Do you think the usage of a phrase "on account" will sound fine in the sentence like: "Should I pay upfront or it goes on account?"

Comment: *.... or will x (the service) be on account?* would be better. If you want to pay later you could ask *may I pay on account* (or *pay in installments*).

Comment: In an informal situation, you could just ask ".. or can I pay you at the end of the week / month?" etc.

Comment: "On account" still sounds a bit off, since I am not a native speaker. But, I will try to get used to it. Thanks!

Comment: If you have an existing account with the supplier, you can say *bill/charge it to my account*.

Answer (score -1):

**Final Settlement**

see 2 below:

> 1. The agreement that ends matters between partners dissolving a partnership.
> 2. The settling of outstanding obligations.

-- [Thelawdictionary.org](https://thelawdictionary.org/final-settlement/)

Also "settlement figure" when used in the context of asking for a quotation for the final settlement amount.

e.g.

> You can request a Settlement Quote... A Settlement Quote details all
>   outstanding money due in order for you to settle your finance with us
>   – including all credit, fees and interest.

--[vwfinance.co.uk](https://www.vwfinance.co.uk/en/privatecustomers/manage_agreement/ending_agreement_early.html)